# Firebase queue. Custom finished state

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-queue

I'm needing launch different specs depending on the data received and don't know how to do this correctly.

I'm trying to declare multiple "finished states" in my spec but it is not working. Is there another way to declare multiple "finished states" for a spec?

Can someone give me a hand? Thanks!

```
checkRelationship.getRequestedsFriendships(data.sender, data.receiver).then(() => {
        data._state='friends_bilateral_commit_start';
        console.log('STARTS BILATERAL COMMIT');
        return resolve(data);

      }).catch((err) => {
        data._state='friends_commit_start';
        console.log('STARTS COMMIT');
        return resolve(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution I suggest is **to stop current task and push a new task to queue**.

I would like to know if you found any implementation for that fork on your tasking work.

I see 'resolve(data)' something like: *put a piece of job on queue*; by *resolving* is just a field change, *state* goes to end value; like *reject*, maybe it is a bit easy to stop current task and start a new one by pushing a *node job* to matching queue.

Cheers, and hope you are doing well with current works!